# I can't seem to register or login on emulator

Tags: android

I can't login to my app or register despite everything looks fine.
I am new to android

here is my signin.java

```
package hushtagstudios.com.towme;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Signin extends AppCompatActivity {

TextInputLayout emailTIL, passwordTIL;
EditText emailET, passwordET;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
CardView cdSignin;
LinearLayout lSignin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(hushtagstudios.com.towme.R.layout.activity_sigin);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)     findViewById(hushtagstudios.com.towme.R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


    emailTIL = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(hushtagstudios.com.towme.R.id.emailTIL);
    passwordTIL = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(hushtagstudios.com.towme.R.id.passwordTIL);
    emailET =(EditText) findViewById(hushtagstudios.com.towme.R.id.email);
    passwordET = (EditText) findViewById(hushtagstudios.com.towme.R.id.password);
    TextView signIn = (TextView) findViewById(hushtagstudios.com.towme.R.id.signin);
    cdSignin = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.cdSignin);
    lSignin = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lSignin);

    emailTIL.setTypeface(Utils.defaultFont(this));
    passwordTIL.setTypeface(Utils.defaultFont(this));
    emailET.setTypeface(Utils.defaultFont(this));
    passwordET.setTypeface(Utils.defaultFont(this));
    signIn.setTypeface(Utils.defaultFont(this));


    signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(emailET.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                emailTIL.setError("email cannot be empty");
            } else if (passwordET.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                passwordTIL.setError("password cannot be empty");
            } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(emailET.getText().toString()).matches()){
                emailTIL.setError("Invalid email");
            } else {
                new process().execute(emailET.getText().toString(),passwordET.getText().toString());
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent openSplash = new Intent(Signin.this, Splash.class);
    startActivity(openSplash);
    finish();
}

private class process extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Signin.this);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... para) {
        try {

            Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            URL url = new URL(Config.url);
            params.put("app_id", Config.appId);
            params.put("app_pass", Config.appPassword);
            params.put("request", Config.login_svc_code);
            params.put("email",para[0]);
            params.put("password",para[1]);

            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
                if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                postData.append('=');
                postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
            }
            String urlParameters = postData.toString();
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            writer.write(urlParameters);
            writer.flush();

            String result = "";
            String line;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

        try {

            JSONObject results = new JSONObject(result);

            if(results.getInt("status") != 1){

                Utils.dialog(Signin.this, results.getString("message"));

            }else{

                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(results.getString("data"));

                Database db = new Database(Signin.this).open();
                db.saveUserDetails(data.getString("id"),  data.getString("firstName"), data.getString("lastName"), data.getString("email"), data.getString("phone"), data.getString("usertype"),
                        data.getString("photo"), data.getString("password"));

                UserDetails.id = data.getString("id");
                UserDetails.firstName = data.getString("firstName");
                UserDetails.lastName = data.getString("lastName");
                UserDetails.email = data.getString("email");
                UserDetails.phone = data.getString("phone");
                UserDetails.usertype = data.getString("usertype");
                UserDetails.photo = data.getString("photo");
                UserDetails.password = data.getString("password");

                Utils.updateSharedPreference(Signin.this,0);
                if(data.getString("usertype").contentEquals("USER")){
                    Intent openLetUsHelp = new Intent(Signin.this, LetUsHelp.class);
                    startActivity(openLetUsHelp);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Intent openLetUsHelp = new Intent(Signin.this, LetUsHelp.class);
                    startActivity(openLetUsHelp);
                    finish();
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Utils.dialog(Signin.this, "An error occurred during  processing of your request. Please try again");
          }
      }
   }`
```

here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hushtagstudios.com.towme">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.Registration"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registration"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.Signin"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sigin"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.MyAccount"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_account"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.InviteAFriend"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_invite_afriend"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.RequestPickup"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_request_pickup"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <!-- [START firebase_service] -->
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- [END firebase_service] -->
        <!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.History"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_history"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.Notifications"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notifications"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.About"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.Help"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.LetUsHelp"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_let_us_help"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.DriveWithTowMe"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drive_with_tow_me"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.BuyInsurance"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_buy_insurance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.JumpStart"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_jump_start"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.TermsAndConditions"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_conditions"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.Accident"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_accident"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.InDitch"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_in_ditch"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.OutOfFuel"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_out_of_fuel"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.MechanicalFault"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mechanical_fault"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.FlatTires"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_flat_tires"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.LockedCar"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_locked_car"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.InsuranceHistory"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_insurance_history"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.InsuranceCalculator"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_insurance_calculator"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.NewInsurance"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_insurance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.RenewInsurance"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_renew_insurance"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.ProposalForm1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_proposal_form"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.InsurancePayment"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_insurance_payment"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.InsuranceDelivery"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_insurance_delivery"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.FareEstimate"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fare_estimate"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity android:name="hushtagstudios.com.towme.SelectMake"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_select_model"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

I can't find any problem with my code.

My logcat is giving me this error

```
11-25 14:22:18.242 1472-1485/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
11-25 14:22:23.206 1472-1485/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
11-25 14:22:24.470 2256-28070/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
11-25 14:22:29.251 1472-1485/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
11-25 14:22:29.662 2755-2903/? E/PlayCommon: [162] com.google.android.play.a.h.a(500): Failed to connect to server: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
11-25 14:22:48.305 2396-3835/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:331873819>, App: com.android.vending, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/experimentsandconfigs
11-25 14:22:48.307 2755-28116/? E/Finsky: [205] com.google.android.finsky.heterodyne.b.a(26): Failed to get auth token
  com.android.volley.AuthFailureError: Error while retrieving auth token
      at com.android.volley.a.b.a(SourceFile:15)
      at com.google.android.finsky.heterodyne.b.a(SourceFile:22)
      at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.core.c.b.a(SourceFile:101)
      at com.google.android.gms.phenotype.core.c.b.a(SourceFile:76)
      at com.google.android.finsky.heterodyne.HeterodyneSyncService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:16)
      at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:68)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
   Caused by: java.io.IOException: NetworkError
      at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:2496)
      at android.accounts.AccountManager.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:2347)
      at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)
11-25 14:23:04.686 2256-28070/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
11-25 14:23:28.378 1472-1485/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
11-25 14:23:28.418 1472-1485/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
11-25 14:23:28.460 2755-2755/? E/Finsky: [2] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
11-25 14:23:29.801 2256-28070/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
11-25 14:24:14.315 1472-1485/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
11-25 14:59:00.036 1472-1489/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
11-25 14:59:00.181 1472-1485/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
11-25 14:59:00.238 2256-28070/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
11-25 14:59:05.279 2256-28070/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
11-25 14:59:10.303 2256-28070/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
```

Comment: your logcat  error doent contain particular error ? please find particular error from logcat

Comment: i've added my logcat

Comment: it has nothing to do with your registration process . you are getting error because of some `UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "play.googleapis.com"`

Comment: does your emulator have google play services? in other words, check your emulator if you have the Play Store. if you do not, get one that has Google Play Services APIs enabled

Comment: yes it does have a play store. what else might be the problem